# How do I make a button that executes the background.js in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a chrome extension. Here is the code:
Manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "My name!",
"version": "2.0",
"description": "Blocks ads",
"permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "shield.ico",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Ad be gone"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"manifest_version": 2
```

}
background.js:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
  { urls: ["*://*.doubleclick.net/*", "*://*.ads.google.com/*",]  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

How would I make a button in popup.html that turns on and off the background.js and alerts the user that it is doing so? I basically want to make a button that turns on and off the ad blocker.